# access protected variable from trait

Tags: php

How to access a protected variable from trait?

```
class Test {
    use Test_trait;

    protected $var = 'wee';
}

trait Test_trait {
    public function get_var(){
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$T = new Test();
$T->get_var();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted should just works fine. A trait doesn't more than just copy the whole content of itself into the class - so you could even access private vars inside the trait!

The transformed code of your class (after the trait is inserted..) would looks like the following.

```
class Test {

    public function get_var(){
        echo $this->var;
    }

    protected $var = 'wee';
}
```

Theres nothing you have to do with your code.

Comment: Just wondering if traits can use the parent's variable just like the example. is it possible or not?